# Generate lexicographic series efficiently in Python

Tags: python, combinations, subset-sum, lexicographic, recursion-schemes

I want to generate a lexicographic series of numbers such that for each number the sum of digits is a given constant. It is somewhat similar to 'subset sum problem'. For example if I wish to generate 4-digit numbers with sum = 3 then I have a series like:

[3 0 0 0]

[2 1 0 0]

[2 0 1 0]

[2 0 0 1]

[1 2 0 0] ... and so on.

I was able to do it successfully in Python with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

M = 4 # No. of digits
N = 3 # Target sum

a = np.zeros((1,M), int)
b = np.zeros((1,M), int)

a[0][0] = N
jj = 0

while a[jj][M-1] != N:
    ii = M-2
    while a[jj][ii] == 0:
          ii = ii-1
    kk = ii
    if kk > 0:
       b[0][0:kk-1] = a[jj][0:kk-1]
    b[0][kk] = a[jj][kk]-1
    b[0][kk+1] = N - sum(b[0][0:kk+1])
    b[0][kk+2:] = 0
    a = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
    jj += 1

for ii in range(0,len(a)):
    print a[ii]

print len(a)
```

I don't think it is a very efficient way (as I am a Python newbie). It works fine for small values of M and N (<10) but really slow beyond that. I wish to use it for M ~ 100 and N ~ 6. How can I make my code more efficient or is there a better way to code it?

Comment: Have a look at [integer composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))

Comment: The given link has very useful information, however, it does not help in refining the algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very effective algorithm adapted from Jorg Arndt book "Matters Computational"
(Chapter `7.2 Co-lexicographic order for compositions into exactly k parts`)

```
n = 4
k = 3

x = [0] * n
x[0] = k

while True:
    print(x)
    v = x[-1]
    if (k==v ):
        break
    x[-1] = 0
    j = -2
    while (0==x[j]):
        j -= 1
    x[j] -= 1
    x[j+1] = 1 + v

[3, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Number of compositions and time on seconds for plain Python (perhaps numpy arrays are faster) for n=100, and k = 2,3,4,5 (2.8 ghz Cel-1840)

```
2  5050 0.040000200271606445
3  171700 0.9900014400482178
4  4421275 20.02204465866089
5  91962520 372.03577995300293
I expect time  2 hours for 100/6 generation
```

Same with numpy arrays (`x = np.zeros((n,), dtype=int)`) gives **worse** results - but perhaps because I don't know how to use them properly

```
2  5050 0.07999992370605469
3  171700 2.390003204345703
4  4421275 54.74532389640808
```

Native code (this is Delphi, C/C++ compilers might optimize better) generates 100/6 **in 21 seconds**

```
3  171700  0.012
4  4421275  0.125
5  91962520  1.544
6  1609344100 20.748
```

Cannot go sleep until all measurements aren't done :)

MSVS VC++:  **18 seconds**! (O2 optimization)

```
5  91962520 1.466
6  1609344100 18.283
```

So 100 millions variants per second. 
A lot of time is wasted for checking of empty cells (because fill ratio is small). Speed described by Arndt is reached on higher k/n ratios  and is about 300-500 millions variants per second:

```
n=25, k=15 25140840660 60.981  400 millions per second
```

Comment: Ran your code for n=100 and k=6, its takes time in this algorithm as well, may be days

Comment: @MBo I find this algorithm to be really fast and efficient. Perfect!

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh Do you know how many compositions with such parameters do exist? Any algorithm generating trillions of variants requires a lot of time. Described approach is very optimized - being implemented in C, it generates 300 millions variants per second (not counting output or writing - the most time consuming part)

Comment: @MBo well that was a part of question lol I didn't add anything to it, 300 millions per sec is very efficient though, Great !

Comment: @Shoyeb Sheikh Yes, I noticed that author supposes to get a lot of variants - it is possible to calculate them, but it is rather hard to store and use such huge amount of data

Comment: @MBo That's a really interesting comparison. I tried it out too for n=100 and k=5, and it took 97 sec approx. BTW do you know if the computation can be parallelized?

Comment: No, this algorithm does not assume parallelization. How are you going to use result data?

Comment: I use it for generating basis to represent wavefunction and further calculations.

Comment: But... 1.6 trillion variants?

Comment: Well...that will be an extreme case, usually n is limited to 64. There are ways to reduce the number of variants further by using symmetries of the system, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution using itertools as follows,

```
from itertools import product
n = 4 #number of elements
s = 3 #sum of elements
r = []
for x in range(n):
    r.append(x)
result = [p for p in product(r, repeat=n) if sum(p) == s]
print(len(result))
print(result)
```

I am saying this is better because it took 0.1 secs on my system, while your code with numpy took 0.2 secs.

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

But as far as n=100 and s=6, this code takes time to go through all the combinations, I think it will take days to compute the results.

Comment: Actually I want to improve the way algorithm is coded (or code a more efficient algorithm) to compute _just the required_ combinations. As far as I understand your code checks _all possible combinations_ against the given sum. Can you time both the codes for M=10, N=3 as well?

Comment: Its been an hour of so for M=10 and N=3 and its still running, I think MBo has a better answer there.

Comment: Nope you check it and let us know

Comment: Ok, I did that. It took less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

1. Rewrite it as a generator utilizing `yield`, rather than a loop that concatenates a global variable on each iteration.
2. Keep a running sum instead of calculating the sum of some subset of the array representation of the number.
3. Operate on a single instance of your working number representation instead of splicing a copy of it to a temporary variable on each iteration.

Note no particular order is implied.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using itertools as well (Source: https://bugs.python.org/msg144273). Code follows:

```
import itertools
import operator

def combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    # combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

int_part = lambda n, k: (tuple(map(c.count, range(k))) for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(k), n))
for item in int_part(3,4): print(item)
```