# Recursively generate all k-digit numbers whose digit-sum is n

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, reverse

I was working on a problem where I'm finding all k-digit numbers whose digits sum up the given n.

I found how to do this and approach it as Integer Partitioning problem, however I would like to be able to only input n and k numbers (without the max_element) but when I try to delete it from the code it doesn't seem to work anymore.

How can I change that plus reverse it?

```py
def c(n, k, max_element):
    allowed = range(max_element, 0, -1)

    def helper(n, k, t):
        if k == 0:
            if n == 0:
                yield t
        elif k == 1:
            if n in allowed:
                yield t + (n,)
        elif 1 * k <= n <= max_element * k:
            for v in allowed:
                yield from helper(n - v, k - 1, t + (v,))
    return helper(n, k, ())

for p in c(5, 3, 3):
    print(p)
```

I tried using the reversed method but apparently it doesn't work in the generator.

Result:

```
(3, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
```

Expected result:

```
113 122 131 212 221 311
```

Comment: @ggorlen oh you are right, I did not notice that. I want to have numbers in an increasing order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here; the first is that you want the numbers in order and this code generates them in reverse order, because of `range(max_element, 0, -1)`. The other problem is that since you're generating digits, the minimum element should be 0 and the maximum element should always be 9. We can fix both by changing that range to `range(10)`.

We still need to be careful not to generate numbers starting with 0, so we'll make `allowed` a parameter and use `range(1, 10)` for just the first digit. I've also changed it to return the result as an integer instead of a tuple.

For reference, the code for this generator function comes from [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915599/generate-restricted-weak-integer-compositions-or-partitions-of-an-integer-n-in/59131521#59131521).

```py
def c(n, k):
    def helper(n, k, t, allowed):
        if k == 0:
            if n == 0:
                yield t
        elif k == 1:
            if n in allowed:
                yield 10*t + n
        elif 0 <= n <= 9 * k:
            for v in allowed:
                yield from helper(n - v, k - 1, 10*t + v, range(10))

    return helper(n, k, 0, range(1, 10))
```

Example:

```py
>>> for p in c(5, 3):
...     print(p)
...
104
113
122
131
140
203
212
221
230
302
311
320
401
410
500
```

Comment: They closed my post so I created a new one with the code you referred me to, but I was trying to delete the max as I only want to input n and k

Comment: Could i then use  `" ".join` to have 104 form instead of (1,0,4) ?

Comment: The problem is to generate *"all k-digit numbers whose digits sum up the given n"* - there isn't anything to suggest 0 should be excluded, except that the OP's code doesn't include 0. I choose not to infer additional requirements from code which is known not to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree, plus it's a pretty trivial difference. Good answer--seems like the optimizations for the extra branch and checking the sum offer a major efficiency boost.

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick

```
def c(n, k, max_element):
    allowed = range(max_element, 0, -1)

    def helper(n, k, t):
        if k == 0:
            if n == 0:
                yield t
        elif k == 1:
            if n in allowed:
                yield t + (n,)
        elif 1 * k <= n <= max_element * k:
            for v in allowed:
                yield from helper(n - v, k - 1, t + (v,))
    return helper(n, k, ())

def reversed_iterator(iter):
    return reversed(list(iter))

for p in reversed_iterator(c(5, 3, 3)):
    print(p)
```

here is the output :

```
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 3, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
```

Comment: This totally defeats the purpose of using an iterator in the first place. `reversed_iterator` doesn't return an iterator as it advertises, it just exhausts the iterator and returns a list.

Comment: What about deleting the max_element ? Any suggestions?