# How to implement an algorithm for generating tuples of arbitrary size with sum of elements = N in python

Tags: python, algorithm, tuples

I am trying to implement a generator function `generate_tuples` which yields every possible combination of numbers with a given sum.

Given a `size`, `elements_sum` so that

```
generate_tuples(size=3, elements_sum=4)
```

it would yield these tuples:

```
(0, 0, 4)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 2)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 4, 0)
(1, 0, 3)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 3, 0)
(2, 0, 2)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 0)
(3, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 0)
(4, 0, 0)
```

For now I ended up with multiple generators for each `size`. For instance:

```
def generate_tuples3(elements_sum: int):
    for x in range(elements_sum + 1):
        for y in range(elements_sum + 1):
            for z in range(elements_sum + 1):
                if sum([x, y, z]) != elements_sum:
                    continue
                yield x, y, z
```

This works, but it's very inefficient and includes a lot of code duplication.

Comment: In combinatorics, these are called the weak compositions of n (`elements_sum`) into k (`size`) parts. I can't make time now to say more, but searching for the right term will uncover a lot for you. It's possible to generate them directly, one at a time, with an efficient loop-free algorithm (although you need a mutable representation to get away with that).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comment posted by Tim Peters, I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915599/generate-restricted-weak-integer-compositions-or-partitions-of-an-integer-n-in) algorithm which is exactly what I need!